# ¿Cómo configurar flutter de manera offline?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Quiero utilizar flutter para desarrollo android. Ya descargué fluter sdk y lo coloqué en el path, ya tengo android sdk y lo agregué a la variable de entorno, incluso descargué gradle. El problema es que no se como decirle a flutter que utilice el gradle que descargué y lo tengo local en mi PC. ¿Alguien sabría como solucionar este problema? Gracias.

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.18362.30], locale es-ES)
> • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.4 at E:\flutter
> • Framework revision cc949a8e8b (5 months ago), 2019-09-27 15:04:59 -0700                                               >• Engine revision b863200c37                                                                                            >• Dart version 2.5.0
> \CreateProcessW failed 740
> CreateProcessW failed 740
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
> • Android SDK at E:\AndroidSDK
> • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
> • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
> • ANDROID_HOME = E:\AndroidSDK
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0\bin\java                                                               X Could not determine java version                                                                                                                                                                                                          [!] Android Studio (not installed)
> • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html                                 (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
> [√] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\Alejo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.8.1
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
> • SM A305G • R58M84Q30VV • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)                                                                                                                                                                               ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: Hola, podrías correr el siguiente comando y compartir el resultado: flutter doctor -v

Comment: Utiliza este comando     flutter doctor --android-licenses , asegúrate de aceptar las licencias. Luego utiliza el comando flutter doctor -v

Comment: Lo utilicé pero me dice que tengo que actualizar Android sdk. Pero eso requiere de una conexión a internet bastante buena. ¿No hay una forma de utilizar ese comando sin actualizar Android sdk?

Comment: Creo que va a ser necesario que actualices.

Comment: Ahora me da un error de que no encuentra las siguientes dependencias cuando ejecuto ```flutter run```   
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom   

       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar   

       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom   

       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar

Comment: Ya solucioné el problema. Al final tuve que utilizar un vpn y funciono perfectamente.

Comment: No es necesario tener Android Studio para usar flutter con el mismo VSCode lo puedes usar tambien, lo que tienes que hacer es poner las variables de entorno para el java y sdk de android en el sistema, digo si usas Windows..lo demas buscando algo de info en internet lo logras..slds

Comment: una VPN??? Para qué? Puedes poner tu respuesta por favor? Con eso otros sabrán qué hacer cuando encuentren este problema. (Después, puedes marcarla como aceptada)

Comment: El problema es que en mi pais no estan disponibles esas dependencias. Entonces tuve que utilizar una VPN para que pudiera descargar las dependencias que faltaban. Hacer una instalacion de flutter 100% offline creo que no se puede. Pero al menos una parte del proceso puedes hacerla offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución que encontré para instalar flutter offline (o al menos una parte) (me refiero a tener todas estas herramientas y pasarlas a otra PC).

- Descargar flutter SDK de la pagina oficial.
- Descargar SDK de Android.
- Instalar un controlador de repositorios como Artifactory o Nexus para almacenar dependencias de gradle (Los repositorios de Artifactory se pueden exportar a otra PC).
- Al menos el primer proyecto de flutter se tendrá que crear de manera online, tambien el primer build.

---

Luego de tener todo esto se pueden crear más proyectos flutter offline (utilizando el flag --offline). Recomiendo utilizar Android Studio porque la mayoria de las acciones intenta hacerlas offline utilizando las caché. Para los paquetes en pub.dev, se pueden descargar y referenciarlos en el pubspec.yaml con el atributo path o simplemente guardando el paquete en la carpeta .pub-cache.
Nota. No lo he intentado pero si tienen un flutter sdk con la mayoría de los pasos (dependencias básicas) ya en cache en teoría funcionaría copiar ese sdk de flutter a otra PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hola AGHA tu error se debe a que no tienes instalado android studio, lastimosamente tienes que descargarlo así no lo vayas a usar, ya que el IDE trae por defecto el sdk de android, ademas de las licencias, prueba con instalarlo y descargarle el plugin de flutter, ademas después de instalado ejecuta el comando flutter doctor --android-licenses a todo le das Y.